# Arrays and React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I created a list :

```
let list = [
    {
      id: 'budget',
      label: 'Budget',
      widget: <Budget />,
      checked: true
    },
    {
      id: 'lastEmployees',
      label: 'LastEmployees',
      widget: <LatestEmployees />,
      checked: true
    },
    {
      id: 'addSection',
      label: 'AddSection',
      widget: <AddSection />,
      checked: true
    }
  ];
```

I neverd used the arrays in React. So I don't understand how I can change the "checked" value at false when we click on a button.

Thanks a lot for your future help

Comment: I think you need to describe your problem better but the simple answer is `list[0].checked = false`

Comment: If this is in a variable like any other then you'd update the value like you would in any other JavaScript code.  If this is stored in state then you'd update that state with the new array.  Perhaps you could include a [mcve] which demonstrates your attempt and describes what isn't working when you try?

Comment: I tried list[0].checked = false but it doesn't works @casr 

Ok I have this button : 
`<Button onClick={ () =>handleClickOpenDialog} sx={{ mx: 2, my: 3 }} variant="contained" color="primary">
          Modifier le Tableau de bord
        </Button>`
which calls this function : 

`const handleClickOpenDialog = () => {
    list[0].checked = false;
  }; ` 

When **checked** of "**label:** AddSection" is set as "true", the box "AddSection" is display. But at false, it's hide. So I would set it state with a button

Comment: React will not consider the `list` array in its render cycle. You will need to use some internal state to the component either through React Hooks, `this.setState`, etc. When you use one of those types of states that React listens to then you will see the component updating.

Comment: I tried as well, but doesn't works. I never used this on an array it's probably the wrong way : 

`const handleClickOpenDialog = () => {
    setList(list[2].checked = false);
  };`

Comment: with this as declaration of array : `const [ list, setList ] = useState([
    {
      id: 'budget',
      label: 'Budget',
      widget: <Budget />,
      checked: true
    },
    {
      id: 'lastEmployees',
      label: 'LastEmployees',
      widget: <LatestEmployees />,
      checked: true
    },
    {
      id: 'addSection',
      label: 'AddSection',
      widget: <AddSection />,
      checked: true
    }
  ]); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Create *useState* to save your list

```
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    {
      id: "budget",
      label: "Budget",
      widget: <Budget />,
      checked: true,
    },
    {
      id: "lastEmployees",
      label: "LastEmployees",
      widget: <LatestEmployees />,
      checked: true,
    },
    {
      id: "addSection",
      label: "AddSection",
      widget: <AddSection />,
      checked: true,
    },
  ]);
```

2- Your function `handleClickOpenDialog`: To update one or many elements in an array you can do this with multiple way, I will show you the method I use the most when I am working with arrays in react usually.

- Create local list.
- Update the element(s) on that local list.
- Call `setState` with new updated list.

like **[Modified]**:

- solution1 (mutating state):

  ```
    const handleClickOpenDialog = () => {
       const updateList = [...list];
       updateList[0].checked = false;
       setList(updateList);

       //list===updateList => false
       //list[0]===updateList[0] => true
    };
  ```
- solution2 (faster + immutating state):

  ```
  const handleClickOpenDialog = () => {
    const updateList = list.map((item) => {
       return { ...item };
    });
    updateList[0].checked = false;
    setList(updateList);

    //list===updateList => false
    //list[0]===updateList[0] => false
  };
  ```

3- Finally

```html
<button onClick={handleClickOpenDialog}>click</button>
```

Comment: You're mutating state in your handler, nested objects aren't cloned when you spread the array. see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323244/how-to-modify-array-within-object-in-react-component-state/68323318#68323318) for two different approaches to avoiding mutation.

Comment: Thank you @pilchard for your comment, like I mentioned before there are multiple way to update array of objects. But to deal with mutable and immutable array/object operation I updated my solution based on your remarks and information provided by [this article](https://dev.to/devcer/cloning-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript-3nng)