# How to change update an object within a useState array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose we have an array of objects in userInformation:

```
[
 {
  firstName:'Bob',
  lastName:'Dude',
 },
 {
  firstName:'John',
  lastName:'Rad',
 }
]
```

```
  const [userInformation, setUserInformation] = useState([]);

   userInformation.forEach((user, index) => {
      if (snapshot.val().leadID === user.leadID) {
        setUserInformation((userInformation) => ({
          ...userInformation,
          [index]: snapshot.val(),
        }));
      }
    });
```

I would like to update the second object.

My code doesn't seem to be working quite right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify array within object in react component state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323244/how-to-modify-array-within-object-in-react-component-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes few suggestions I have for you:)

First of all you have never assigned userinformation to your state.
So it should be some what like below

```
const [userInformation, setUserInformation] = useState(userinformation);
```

Or you must be getting userinformation from an API and using `useEffect` to initialize it.

Second thing is you must have an `id` as well as `index` key on each **user** something like this:

```
[
 {
  leadId:1,
  firstName:'Bob',
  lastName:'Dude',
  index:1
 },
 {
  leadId:2,
  firstName:'John',
  lastName:'Rad',
  index:2
 }
]
```

Now, Coming to what you are expecting you can use `map()` function in such as way that once the condition is met, you update that particular **user**, otherwise you should return back same users when condition is not met.

```
 const updatedUsers = userInformation.map((user, index) => {
   if (snapshot.val().leadID === user.leadID) {
     return setUserInformation((userInformation) => ({
        ...userInformation,
      [index]: snapshot.val(),
     }));
   }
    return userInformation;
 });
```

Comment: Hello I appreciate the response!

const [userInformation, setUserInformation] = useState(userinformation);


Gave me this error `Cannot access 'userInformation' before initialization`

Each user had a leadID associated with it, but after I ran your code, It returns undefined?

Comment: @ozansozuoz Hello My Friend. It is because, the names are the same, I knew this would throw an error my Friend. I had just given it as an example. Simply change the array name or state name. If you can simple rename your Array and then assign the same to the `useState` suppose if you name your array as `userData` instead of `userInformation` and then assign it to your state as 
`const [userInformation, setUserInformation] = useState(userData);` 


Other option is to change the name of your state and where that is replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Here I think a simple `find()` would do the trick, rather than trying to loop the array.

```
const updateInfo = (id, obj /* snapshot.val() */) => {
   const item = userInformation.find(({ leadID }) => leadID === id);
   const updatedItem = {
      ...item,
      ...obj
   };
   
   setUserInformation((previousInfo) => {
      ...userInformation,
      ...updatedItem 
   })
}
```

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your response! But when I try to set the user information,   setUserInformation((previousInfo) => {
      ...userInformation, -----> right here there is an error saying declaration or statement expected
      ...updatedItem 
   })

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lack of information provided in my question.

I was using firebase realtime with React, and not wrapping my logic in a useEffect was one problem.

I went with this solution:

```
  setUserInformation(
        userInformation.map((user) =>
          user.leadID === snapshot.val().leadID
            ? {
                ...user,
                ...snapshot.val(),
              }
            : user
        )
      );
```

Thank you for all your answers!